# How to use builder pattern with Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, builder

I would like to eliminate too many of "new" creation in my code.
So I decided to use builder pattern. I also would like to take advantage of Spring @Autowired if possible.

```
public class Car
{
    @Autowired
    private Radio radio;

    @Autowired
    private Speaker speaker;

    @Autowired
    private Engine engine;

    private String model;

    public Car createCar()
    {
        radio.add(speaker);
        return this;
    }

    public static class Builder
    {
        private String model;

        public Builder(){}

        public Builder model(String model)
        {
            this.model = model;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use perhaps something like this.

```
Car car = new Car.Builder().model("A123").build();
```

Would this be possible to do?

Comment: why do you want to build the instances, when spring does that for you?

Comment: Because there are some variables I would like to keep changing. For example the model A123 or next time B658. But Radio need speaker and car need radio.

Answer (score 1):

Ok You Can Use Something similar with some basic changes 
First You make the car and the builder with default autowired instances then you change the as you want here an example :

Car.calss

```
public class Car {
    private Radio radio;
    private Speaker speaker;
    private Engine engine;

    public Car(Radio radio, Speaker speaker, Engine engine) {
        this.radio = radio;
        this.speaker = speaker;
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public Radio getRadio() {
        return radio;
    }

    public void setRadio(Radio radio) {
        this.radio = radio;
    }

    public Speaker getSpeaker() {
        return speaker;
    }

    public void setSpeaker(Speaker speaker) {
        this.speaker = speaker;
    }

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

CarBuilder.class

```
@Component
public class CarBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private Radio radio;
    @Autowired
    private Speaker speaker;
    @Autowired
    private Engine engine;

    public CarBuilder setRadio(Radio radio) {
        this.radio = radio;
        return this;
    }

    public CarBuilder setSpeaker(Speaker speaker) {
        this.speaker = speaker;
        return this;
    }

    public CarBuilder setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
        return this;
    }

    public Car createCar() {
        return new Car(radio, speaker, engine);
    }

}
```

and to use the builder in your code its like the following

```
@Component
public class CarMarket {

    @Autowired
    private CarBuilder carBuilder;

    private Car buildStandardCar(){
        return carBuilder.createCar();
    }


    private Car buildStandardCarButDifferentRadio(Radio radio){
        return carBuilder.setRadio(radio).createCar();
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Why will we have same properties in Car and CarBuilder?

Comment: @user3689942 if you are a car assembler and you need to build a car first you have them separated then you start to combine them together then you build the car ... the key concept here is that we have them in the builder to give more flexibility

Comment: One of the most important reasons for builders is to facilitate immutable instances. If that's what you want (and according to the esteemed Josh Block and many others, you *do* want it), then `Car`'s private members should all be final, and `Car` should have no setters. To enforce use of the builder, visibility of `Car`'s constructor should be limited. If you move `CarBuilder` inside `Car` and make it a static inner class, you can make `Car`'s constructor private. Failing that, you can at least use package visibility (no `public` or `private` specified) for `Car`'s constructor.

Comment: @nclark yes sure , what youve said is true and im with you 100% but the answer was to give an idea about it not what's the optimal implementation for the pattern ... thanks :)

Comment: @MhmdSalem We should also strive to put good usage examples out there so as not to spread anti-patterns in the community.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
@Component
    public class Car {
@Autowired
private Radio radio;
@Autowired
    private Speaker speaker;
@Autowired
    private Engine engine;  
private String model;
    }
```

Then a builder class:

```
    @Component
    public class CarBuilder{
@Autowired
Car car;

public void addModel(String model){
this.car.setModel(model);
}

public Car getCar(){
return car;
}
}
```

Then main class

```
 class Main{

public static void main(String args[]){
     Car car= context.getBean("carBuilder").addModel("abc").getCar();
}
}
```

Comment: No mutators required with Autowired annotation.

Comment: this.car.setModel(model); !! and What is this !